# How to make segments

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Hello can anyone help me to understand how to describe segments on the Cartesian plane using Cartesian products.

Like for example, how can I interpret

$$(-\infty,-1) \times (-\infty,-1)$$

and

$$(0,1) \times (-\infty,1)$$

How could this be expanded for example/ what is it really saying?

I am only used to the product with the basic examples, such as when you have individual elements in a set A and a set B.

Thank you to anyone for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get all the points $(x,y)$ where $$-\infty < x < -1$$                       & $$-\infty < y < -1$$ Basically, an "infinite" rectangle (red) with its upper right corner at $(-1,-1)$ (which itself is not included, since you have two open sets).

[image]

Analogously for the second example (blue): This time you have

$$0 < x < 1$$
$$-\infty < y < -1$$

being a rectangle which is $1$ unit broad (upper edge between $(0,-1)$ and $(1,-1)$) and starts stretching infinitely downwards after $y=-1$. Again, its edges are not included since you have round brackets instead of squared ones.

Answer (score 1):

For the second set, $(0,1)$ means $0<x<1$ since its first in the product. So graph dotted vertical lines $x=0,x=1$ and remember you're shading between these. The lines are dotted to indicate boundary points not in set. Then your second factor $(-\infty,1)$ means just $y<1,$ so plot the horizontal line $y=1$ (again dotted since it's $<$ not $\le$) This time you'll shade below that line. Put the two together (or consider where both shadings occur).